# Passing arrays via reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm fairly new to C++ and I recently came across this problem.

This code will obviously work:

```
void setvalues(int *c, int *d)
{
    (*c) = 1;
    (*d) = 2;
}
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    setvalues(&a, &b);
    std::cout << a << b;
}
```

So why does this return an error? Visual C++ 2010 error:

> `C2664: 'setvalues' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (*)[2]' to 'int *[]'`

```
void setvalues(int *c[2], int *d[2])
{
   (*c[1]) = 1;
   (*d[1]) = 2;
}
int main()
{
    int a[2], b[2];
    setvalues(&a, &b);
    std::cout << a[1] << b[1];
}
```

What's different about pointers to arrays? I searched around but no luck.

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*c%5B2%5D) is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type `int *a[2]` means *array of 2 pointers to `int`*, but the expression `&a` with the definition `int a[2]` means *pointer to an array of 2 `int`*. Both are different types and there is no conversion among them. As Vlad already mentioned, to provide the proper type you need to add parenthesis:

```
void setvalues( int (*c)[2] )
```

Or you could use actual *references* in C++:

```
void setvalues( int (&c)[2] )
```

In the later case you don't need to use the *address-of* operator or dereference it inside the `setvalue` function:

```
int a[2];
setvalues(a); // this is a reference to the array
```

A simpler way to write the code is to use `typedef`:

```
typedef int twoints[2];
void setvalue( toints& c );
int main() {
   twoints a; // this is int a[2];
   setvalue(a);
}
```

Comment: I get it now, thanks. I assume it's the same for arrays of strings too?

Comment: @user1867129: It depends on what you mean by *string*, but the syntax is consistent for all types, if you want to use a pointer to an array you have to use the inverted parenthesis (inverted in the sense that the parenthesis in `int (*a)[2]` actually group everything that is *outside* the parenthesis: *a is a pointer to the type described outside of the parens*)

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be `void setvalues(int (&c)[2], int (&d)[2])` to pass by reference. And a caller must be `setvalues(a, b);`. Otherwise you are passing pointers by pointers at best.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you fix it:

```
void setvalues(int c[], int d[])
{
   c[1] = 1;
   d[1] = 2;
}
int main()
{
    int a[2],b[2];
    setvalues(a, b);
    std::cout<<a[1]<<b[1];
}
```

When you declare an array like this: `int a[2],b[2];`, then `a` and `b` are already pointers to the start of these arrays.

And when you do `a[0]`, that is when you actually deference the array at some offset to access the element in the array. `a[1]`, for example, is the same as `*(a+1)`

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: This is not entirely correct because it is the same as passing by pointer. What's the length of that array? It is enforced during compile time? No..